# Wordpress: How do I make a new page similar to this one?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, directory

I am extending an existing plugin. It is a Q&A plugin. After submitting a question successfully, I want it to be redirected to another page to fill out another form. I found the place where I can change the redirect location (currently, I made it redirect to http://www.google.com) but now I want to make a proper page in WP where I will have a form that users need to fill out.

I noticed that the page where users fill out the question looks like this:

`http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/questions/ask/`

How did they make that structure? A general answer would get me started in figuring this all out. I like how the `/questions/` part is the main page of the plugin and then the `/ask/` part is a link on the main page. How do I make *my page* a subset of `/ask/`?

Comment: How can we access a `localhost` link ???

Comment: @RaphaëlVigée first we have to break in to his house

Comment: That's a good starting point haha

Comment: @RaphaëlVigée well I guess the online site has a different structure than the one on my localhost. The uploaded site's page is this: `http://www.efficientmind.org/?page_id=73&ap_page=ask` but as you can see, the structure is different and I like the nice slugs in the original question :)

Comment: google wp rewrite and query vars , it should get you going.

Comment: @David Sweet, thanks!